# Triggering CSS :active selector for non-anchor elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

How do I trigger the :active state for non-anchor elements via JavaScript (jQuery)?

---

While reviewing [Section 5.11.3 of the W3C CSS2 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#dynamic-pseudo-classes) in reference to :hover pseudo selector to see about triggering the activation of a , I came across the following which led me to believe it should be possible:

> "The :active pseudo-class applies while an element is being activated by the user. For example, between the times the user presses the mouse button and releases it."
>
> "CSS does not define which elements may be in the above states, or how the states are entered and left. Scripting may change whether elements react to user events or not, and different devices and UAs may have different ways of pointing to, or activating elements."

Thanks for the assist!

Answer (score 4):

You can't trigger a css pseudo selector like `:active` with javascript.
There is no function / handler which could be executed, so even if you `trigger` a `click` on an element which has a `css :active` pseudo selector set (setting the background color to red for instance), nothing is going to happen.

Comment: That is disappointing if true.  I know I haven't found a way to do it, but I don't see why there shouldn't be. =(

Comment: I'm wondering if this is still the case, almost twelve years later

Comment: @darksoulsong As of today, it is. You can call `focus()` which triggers `:focus` but you cannot trigger `:active`.

Answer (score 4):

i came across this question while searching for the exact same thing.

basically i have a text area and a button. button.click is triggered when the user press enter. however the :active selector in css is not triggered so it doesnt give the same affect.

so this is what i did. its a little redundant but works.

in the css

```
/*this is for actual clicks on the button */
.Button:active {
position:relative;
top:5px;
}

/* this is for pressing enter instead of clicking the button */
.Button.activate{
position:relative;
top:5px;
}
```

then in jquery

```
//if enter is pressed, trigger button click
$("#textArea").keydown(function(event){
if(event.keyCode == 13){
    $("#button").click();
    $("#button").addClass('activate');
}
});

//if enter is released, remove class
$("#textArea").keyup(function(event){
if(event.keyCode == 13){
    $("#button").removeClass('activate');
}
});
```

Comment: Using `.Button:active,.Button.activate { ... }` in the css rule would allow you to define the styling only once and removes the redundancy problem.