# Use jQuery to click an element while triggering css :active

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a button `div`:

```
<div id="hud-button1"> </div>
```

I attached a listener to it:

```
$('#hud-button1').click(function(){ //Do Stuff });
```

And it has a CSS `:active` rule:

```
#hud-button1:active { /* .. */ }
```

So far so good. Now i want to add the option to trigger this button by pressing a key:

```
window.onkeyup = function(e) {
    var key = e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which;

    if (key == 87) { $('#hud-button1').click(); }
}
```

While this works, i want the button to show the small "animation" it plays via the `:active` rule.

I am aware that i could add a class and remove it quickly, but the button will be mashed quickly and a lot, so im afraid that the `Timeouts` would interfere and bug. Is there any clean solution to this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: This may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2990687/triggering-css-active-selector-for-non-anchor-elements

Comment: So clean up timeouts... `if(myTimeout) window.clearTimeout(myTimeout); myTimeout = window.setTimeout(...);`

Comment: This is a duplicate, and there's no way to do this.

Comment: @RUJordan Thank you, that actually helps a lot! I'll try it and post an answer if it works out nicely.

Comment: `:active` is maintained while you keep down the mouse, so why not maintain some class while the key is kept down? then remove the class if it's up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your help, i solved it exactly as proposed, a class similar to the `:active` selector is being attached on `keydown` and removed on `keyup`.

That way it feels very responsive and no timeouts interfere.

```
$( document ).keydown(function(event){
    if(event.keyCode == 81){
        $("#hud-button1").click().addClass('active');
    }
    });

    $( document ).keyup(function(event){
    if(event.keyCode == 81){
        $("#hud-button1").removeClass('active');
    }
    });
}
```

Comment: Could you not chain the `addClass()` and `.click()` ?