# How to play css transition effect from javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, asp.net

I'm trying to play a sound when user clicks a button on screen. I have bound these buttons with keyboard keys. Like there is a button with id='A' which is bound to the keyboard key 'A'. So if user presses the key'A' from keyboard or presses the on screen button, the java script function written on that button will be called.

Here is the problem:

I have applied below css on buttons, which works fine if i click the on screen button. The desired ripple effect is shown. But when i press the keyboard button, the effect does not work.

To bind the keys i have written following JS code.

```js
    document.onkeydown = function(e) {
      e = e || window.event;
      var key = (e.which || e.keyCode),
        pressed = {
          65: 'A',
          83: 'S'
        };

      if (typeof pressed[key] === 'undefined')
        return;

      document.getElementById(pressed[key]).click();
    }
```

```css
.button {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  border: none;
  font-size: 28px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.4s;
  /* Safari */
  transition-duration: 0.4s;
  text-decoration: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.button:after {
  content: "";
  background: #f1f1f1;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  padding-top: 300%;
  padding-left: 350%;
  margin-left: -20px !important;
  margin-top: -120%;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 0.8s
}
.button:active:after {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: 0s
}
```

```html
<button class="button" type="button" id="A">A</button>
<button class="button" type="button" id="S">S</button>
```

So how can i show the ripple effect even when the user presses the keyboard key?

Comment: So is your problem solved now? You haven't commented any further and also haven't marked an answer as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you cannot use `:active` alone here since Javascript is unable to trigger that state. Instead additonally create a class `.active` and put it on the element.

```
.button.active:after { ... }
```

See [Triggering CSS :active selector for non-anchor elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2990687/triggering-css-active-selector-for-non-anchor-elements)

Since it kind of touches the topic, the [global `accesskey` attribute](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/editing.html#the-accesskey-attribute) might be interesting for you as well.

Comment: Thank you @connexo for your reply. I am pretty new to html and css. I tried doing what you said like so : <code> .button.active:after { padding: 0; margin: 0; opacity: 1; transition: 0s } </code> . But by doing so the css of the button completely disappeared. Please tell me what i'm doing wrong. Thank you again for your effort

Comment: You need to add/remove that `.active` class based on `:focus` and `:blur` states, alternatively based on click/keydown events.